# Executing two functions sequentially on one onclick - add to cart and pass variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart2.x

I have two functions that do the following:-
myFunction() sends variable/s to checkout
myFunction2() adds a product to the cart and proceeds to cart.
The framework requires that a product is added to the cart before proceeding to checkout. 
I am battling to get the two functions to add sequentially through one onclick.

There are three possible inputs(for testing), namely,
"Add to Cart" - uses an href to add a product to the cart (submits correctly)
"Submit form" - which sends variables to the checkout if the product is already added to the cart, but because "Add to Cart" has already proceeded to the cart page, you have to go back to the form to run. (submits correctly, subject to the above)
 "Click" - attempts to combine the two functions?, routes to cart page and say no items in cart - so not working as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<?php $postvalue = array (12,2,3,"7 days"); ?>

    <form id="myForm" action="index.php?route=checkout/checkout" method="post">
        First name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="product_id" value="30">
        <?php 
            foreach($postvalue as $onx)
        {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="onx[]" value="'. $onx . '">';
        } ?>
            <br>

            <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
    </form>

</body>

<!-- THIS FUNCTION WORKS TO ADD A PRODUCT TO Cart -->
<a href='index.php?route=checkout/cart/addToCart&product_id=30' id="addtocart" onclick="myFunction2();">Add to Cart</a>
<br />
```

```
<script>
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("addtocart");
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>

</html>
```

I would like to be able to add a product to cart as well as posting variable/s to checkout in the correct sequential order for further code execution.

Comment: create a new function that encapsulates both function1 & function2 ie: 
function addToCartAndSubmit(){ myFunction(); myFunction2(); } 
then call this function?

Comment: Thanks Marty but same result. Functions work independently but not together??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the product by visiting the URL you can use AJAX to make an ansychronous request and add the product while staying in the same page.So remove the href attribute.
(I use `return false;` to prevent default event handling for the onclick event)

```
<a href="#" id="addtocart" onclick="myFunction2(); return false;">Add to Cart</a>
```

And add the code to perform the request in the click handler.
When the request returns successfully you can just add a class to the form so you will know the product has been added.
(in the example i use jQuery for the AJAX call).

```
function myFunction2() {

    $.get( "index.php?route=checkout/cart/addToCart&product_id=30", function( data ) {
    $( "#myForm" ).addClass( "product-added" ); 
   });

}
```

Before submit the form just check that the product has been added to the cart

```
function myFunction() {

    if($( "#myForm" ).hasClass( "product-added" )){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }

}
```

Comment: I followed as I understood, but it doesn't appear to work. Click "Add to cart" and nothing happens. It seems it is trying to execute the empty href:- http://localhost/addto.php#

Comment: Update:- It does add to cart. It doesn't appear to be posting the variable though. I will update as I progress, but your code seems to have helped thus far.

Comment: Update:- Works great - is posting variable now, I had not added the class to the form gracia.

Comment: @AdrianBo Happy I could help you.If the answer solved your problem pleace accept it as the correct answer.